# how to config a admin role which can access all url in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

all doc judge url first then the role, like this

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/aaa/xxx").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/aaa/yyy").hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
    .antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("WORKER")
```

but I want judge role first, like this

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    // first judge role
    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN").permitAll()
    // then judge url 
    .antMatchers("/aaa/yyy").hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
    .antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("WORKER")
```

I want to judge the role first. if the role isnot ADMIN then judge the url and its role.

**I want ADMIN can access both "/aaa/yyy" and ''/aaa/ccc" , and others.**

there is a stupid way to implement, that is add all "ADMIN" in all hasAnyRole() method, like this

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/aaa/yyy").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","MANAGER")
    .antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","WORKER")
    # .... there is many many antMatchers() need add "ADMIN"
```

I don't want the way, I need another better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/aaa/yyy").hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
    .antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("WORKER") //you can put here many roles .hasAnyRole("WORKER", "MANAGER")
    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
```

Comment: it not work, I want MANAGER can access both "/aaa/yyy" and ''/aaa/ccc" but you answser can not work when access "/aaa/ccc". it still reponse a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Read comment in the code `.antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("WORKER",  "MANAGER")`

Comment: Btw, you can change the order, then:
`http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
    .antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("WORKER")
    `

Comment: that is no true, if I use ```http.authorizeRequests() .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("MANAGER") .antMatchers("/aaa/ccc").hasAnyRole("WORKER")``` , when a WORKER access "/aaa/ccc" it return 403, maybe it match ```.anyRequest().hasAnyRole("MANAGER") ``` and return false

Comment: Yes, you are right, Spring should take the first matched pattern, but the first solution should work for you

Comment: my project have many many many antMatchers("/...") , so I need  add many many many "ADMIN". it's too ugly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184378/discussion-between-usrmqj-xv-and-andrew-sasha).